# how to get deleted items from parse platform database?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, parse-platform

I'm working on an application that requires offline operation, and the  Parse local datastore not work for me.
when some change occurs while the application is closed, that is, the subscriptions are not active, i can get created and updated items with createdAt and updatedAt fields, but in case of deleted items, i cant recover them.
any idea about how to solve this

I thought about creating a field that records the date it was "removed", and using it as a filter to remove them from my application

```
const createdAt = new Parse.Query("AnyClass");
createdAt.greaterThan("createdAt", new Date(1560443963000));

const updatedAt = new Parse.Query("AnyClass");
updatedAt.greaterThan("updatedAt",  new Date(1560443963000) );

const mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(createdAt, updatedAt);
mainQuery.find()

// deleted at ???...
```

Comment: If a record has been deleted then it has been removed from the database. So if you make a new query it won't return the deleted records so then you can update your app accordingly.

Comment: my application works with tables that have more than 10000 records, because of a performance problem of both the server and the application I can not download all the data every time I need to validate that there is data deleted. that's why I work by storing the data as files on the device and keep it synchronized with the server through subscriptions, but I can not find a way to resolve the synchronization of the deleted elements

Comment: I'd recommend you to create a "soft delete" functionality in your class. It means that you'd need to create an additional column called "deletedAt". Instead of actually deleting the objects, you'd set this field and then you'd use this field to know objects were/were not/when were deleted. Another idea would be creating an extra class called "DeletedObject" containing deletedObjectId field. You can create a afterDelete trigger in the main class to create a record in this extra class everytime you have an object deleted. You can use the createdAt in the extra class to know when it was deleted.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo thank you very much, I think I'll go for this solution